# Javascript not working on a specific URL Webview Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webview

```java
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.clearFormData();
        myWebView.clearHistory();
        myWebView.clearCache(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

        myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://pokerlv3.draft10.com/");


        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }



        });
```

It works fine with everyother link except "http://pokerlv3.draft10.com/" this one

This is a simple webview with a link in it. This link works fine when opened in any mobile browser. But once I open it in webview, Javascript doesnot work. I cannot interact with the page any more. Html loads perfectly

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Why you mentioned react native for this questions?

Comment: @Manojkanth facing same when using React Native Webview. Every other link works fine. You can try on Snack placing it in a simple webview